# Name of comic where protagonist finds his past, dead self

Tags: story-identification, comics, 2000ad

I'm looking for the name of a comic, or at least the name of the character to which it belongs. This comic was probably published in the early 90s. It possibly belongs to 2000 AD, or at least certainly had the same tone and art style as Judge Dredd and ABC Warriors.

My memory of this is hazy, but it involves our hero at the very beginning being teleported to a universe/time where the antagonist has won. We don't see where the protagonist comes from and the antagonist is alone (on his spaceship?). The antagonist's base is absolutely full of skeletons, and the protagonist eventually discovers his own corpse (it is only a skeleton but his modifications/mutations makes it obvious that it belonged to him).

The end of the story involves the protagonist leaving, and the antagonist left to his lonely fate.

It's a weird one and the visuals stuck with me, but I cannot come up with anything that would make it readily searchable. I am fairly certain the protagonist was bright blue (with horns I think).

Comment: If you are remembering the blue skin correctly, then it's probably the long running Rogue Trooper, or one of the spin-off strips. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_Trooper  The strip was rebooted in 1989 with a similar but different blue soldier named Friday. This would probably be the version you saw. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_(2000_AD)  I don't remember individual storylines. There's also the Tor Cyan strip, about a blue skinned medical shuttle driver in the same continuity.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_Cyan